# How to tail a binary file over ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, tail

I have a log file in a custom binary format sitting on a remote machine. I want to sync it with a file on my local machine, so when new bytes are appended to the remote binary file, the file on my local machine will be updated as well.

I learned about how to use `tail` over ssh here: https://serverfault.com/questions/608723/tail-a-file-from-ssh-and-mirror-to-a-local-file

Then I learned about how to use `tail` on binary files here: [Binary "tail" a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232212/binary-tail-a-file)

I tried combining them into

```
ssh -t remotebox "tail -c +1 -f /path/to/file.bin" > ./mirror.bin
```

But then I realized that `mirror.bin` is corrupted. Looking at the hex dump, I see that all `0d0a` bytes are truncated into `0a`s (`\r\n` got replaced by just `\n`). However, if I run tail locally (`tail -c +1 -f file1.bin > file2.bin`), this truncation does not happen.

I also tried to use `tee` instead of redirection; the problem persists.

Are there shell tricks I can do with tail to prevent this from happening, or are there other programs that suites my needs?

Thanks.

P.S. Both remote and local machines are Linux, running bash.

Comment: Are there two different systems with different line ending involved (e.g. Linux and Windows)?

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, both are Linux. I've added that to the description.

Comment: You should ask this question on Serverfault or Unix/Linux. It's unrelated to programming.

Comment: I think the problem is that `tail` and `tee` are focused on text. Therefore the line endings are converted. You could check the documentation if there is a binary option.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks for the suggestion, I've posted the question on Unix/Linux. The thing is tail on the local machine doesn't have this problem, so I suspect something in SSH is to blame.

Comment: Please post `tail --version` on both machines... but I strongly do not believe it's `tail` fault. This is very strange. Would you be able to setup a [MCVE]? Create a test files with `\r\n` ndings, `scp` to remote machine, `ssh+tail` it back to local and `diff`? I just did `echo -e '123\r\n234\r\n' > /tmp/1; scp /tmp/1 server:/tmp/1 ; timeout 1 ssh server tail -c +1 -f /tmp/1 > /tmp/2 ; diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2` and got back the same file. Och `ssh -t` is at fault here!

Comment: Seems like when I turn off `-t` everything is fine... I will play with it a bit more to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reproduces the problem:

```
$ echo -e '123\r\n234\r\n' > /tmp/1
$ scp /tmp/1 server:/tmp/1
$ ssh -t server cat /tmp/1 > /tmp/2
Shared connection to closed.
$ diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2
1,3c1,3
< 123
< 234
< 
---
> 123
> 234
>
```

It's possible that `ssh -t` changes `\r\n` to `\n` because it might do `stty +igncr` on the line. Mine `ssh -t` does the opposite (I think `stty +inlcr`) and I have the character doubled:

```
$ ssh -t server cat /tmp/1 | hexdump -C
Shared connection to  closed.
00000000  31 32 33 0d 0d 0a 32 33  34 0d 0d 0a 0d 0a        |123...234.....|
0000000e
$ ssh server cat /tmp/1 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 32 33 0d 0a 32 33 34  0d 0a 0a                 |123..234...|
0000000b
```

Anyway. remove the `-t` option if you do not have the intention to use terminal features.

And your command line suggest that you are copying a file. I have no idea why do you use `tail` for that - `tail` it's for outputting last part of file, not for printing the whole file... To print the whole file use `cat`. To copy a file, use `scp`.

Comment: The reason I'm using tail is that the remote file is constantly being appended and I want to get the new content as soon as possible on my local machine. Since it's a log file, tail seems to perform a bit better than rerunning rsync.